# What does the 'Validating Web Site' step do when building an ASP.Net website?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, compiler-construction, web

It's taking some time to do every time I debug my application. Is it something I can speed-up or skip?

Answer (score 2):

Validating the website would generally mean running it against all the rules set up for W3C validation for the type of HTML/XHTML you are using. If there are any validation problems, they would generally show up as warnings on your error list.

Comment: So I should be able to turn this off?

Comment: that is up to you. I personally wouldn't turn it off because as a web developer, meeting the W3C standards as well as other standards that deal with handicap accessibility are important to me in delivering a good product that will work on most browsers. There should be settings where you can adjust the level of the validation that is done, but if I were you I would just put up with the few extra seconds of loading time when debugging your project.

Comment: A few extra minutes each build is not acceptable. But I do have validation turned off in 'Text Editor'/'HtTML'/'Validation', are there any other options for this?